# Overriding builtin mobile alerts via j2me or Sending SMS silently

Tags: java-me, nokia

I have designed an app which sends a number of SMS for performing an action, on each message send it shows builtin alerts from the mobile phone  "Sending text message" & then "text message sent". Is there any way to override this annoying message and displaying my own alert there? I have tried to put alert there, but when it comes to send SMS mobile shows it's own at top and after completing the process shows my alert! What to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use nokia sdk and you also need a little hack. [Please see this](http://www.mobile-j.de/snipsnap/comments/J2ME/Sending+SMS+from+MIDlet+without+user+intervention)

I dont know is this work in latest model or not but hope for the best.